# WCF service creating multiple internal objects?

Tags: wcf, service

I am self-hosting a WCF service and wish my service object to be a singleton.  My client uses a channel to access the service.  Host and client are console apps and are listed below.

My service has a method that returns an interface to an internal object.  That internal object contains methods to get/set a number.  My service has alternate methods to get/set that internal object’s number.

My problem is that setting the internal object’s number through the interface returned by the service and setting it with the service method (SetInternalNumber) do not appear to be setting the same object.  When I retrieve the values, they are different.

My client app shows the initial number of the internal object, changing that number, getting **another** interface to the object and its initial value, setting the value through the service, and a listing of the differing values.

I thought that multiple instances of my internal object were created, but that doesn’t seem to be the case. I know this because I printed a line in the object constructor and I only see that line once.

What is going on?  I thought that maybe the Internal class had to be marked as a singleton (InstanceContextMde.Single), but that did not work.

Service interface

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IMyService
{
    [OperationContract]
    [ServiceKnownType(typeof(Internal))]
    IInternal GetMyInterface();

    [OperationContract]
    int GetInternalNumber();

    [OperationContract]
    void SetInternalNumber(int number);
}
```

Service implementation

```
[ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.Single)]
public class MyService : IMyService
{
    private IInternal _internal;

    public MyService()
    {
        Random rng = new Random();
        _internal = new Internal(rng.Next());
    }

    public int GetInternalNumber()
    {
        return _internal.GetNumber();
    }

    public IInternal GetMyInterface()
    {
        return _internal;
    }

    public void SetInternalNumber(int number)
    {
        _internal.SetNumber(number);
    }
}
```

Internal object interface

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IInternal
{
    [OperationContract]
    int GetNumber();

    [OperationContract]
    void SetNumber(int number);
}
```

Internal object implementation

```
[DataContract]
public class Internal : IInternal
{
    [DataMember]
    private int _number;

    public Internal(int number)
    {
        _number = number;
        Console.WriteLine($"creating Internal - {_number}");
    }

    public int GetNumber()
    {
        return _number;
    }

    public void SetNumber(int number)
    {
        _number = number;
    }
}
```

Self-host app

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Uri baseAddress = new Uri(@"http://localhost:12345/GettingStarted");            
        MyService singleton = new MyService();
        ServiceHost selfHost = new ServiceHost(singleton, baseAddress);

        try
        {
            selfHost.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IMyService), new BasicHttpBinding(), "MyService");
            ServiceMetadataBehavior smb = new ServiceMetadataBehavior();
            smb.HttpGetEnabled = true;
            selfHost.Description.Behaviors.Add(smb);

            selfHost.Open();

            Console.WriteLine("host is open");
            Console.ReadLine();

            selfHost.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"exception: {ex.Message}");
            Console.ReadLine();

            selfHost.Abort();
        }
    }
```

Client app

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var myBinding = new BasicHttpBinding();
        var myEndpoint = new EndpointAddress(@"http://localhost:12345/GettingStarted/MyService");

        using (var myChannelFactory = new ChannelFactory<IMyService>(myBinding, myEndpoint))
        {
            IMyService service = null;

            try
            {
                service = myChannelFactory.CreateChannel();

                Console.WriteLine("channel created");

                // get interface to concrete object 
                IInternal myInternal = service.GetMyInterface();
                Console.WriteLine($"initial number = {myInternal.GetNumber()}");

                Console.ReadLine();

                // set a new # with Internal interface
                Console.WriteLine("set new number");
                myInternal.SetNumber(123);
                Console.WriteLine($"new number = {myInternal.GetNumber()}");

                Console.ReadLine();

                // get another interface, don't set its number
                Console.WriteLine("get another interface, initial value");
                IInternal anotherInternal = service.GetMyInterface();
                Console.WriteLine($"number(another) = {anotherInternal.GetNumber()}");

                Console.ReadLine();

                // set # with service
                Console.WriteLine("set # through server");
                service.SetInternalNumber(789);                    

                // what are the #s?
                Console.WriteLine();
                Console.WriteLine($"from Internal: {myInternal.GetNumber()}");                    
                Console.WriteLine($"from another Internal = {anotherInternal.GetNumber()}");
                Console.WriteLine($"from service = {service.GetInternalNumber()}");

                Console.ReadLine();

                ((ICommunicationObject)service).Close();
                myChannelFactory.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                Console.ReadLine();

                (service as ICommunicationObject)?.Abort();
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Wcf is a communication framework which sends message and receives message.

Your method GetMyInterface which returns the internal will first be serialized into xml and then when client receives message it will deserialize the message to rebuild the object.

This means if your method returns an object, it will be always not the same object and has nothing to do with the internal in your service because the client rebuild it from message. 
You could have a test as follows

```
 Console.WriteLine($"are the two internal the same?" + (myInternal == anotherInternal ? "the same" : "not the same"));
```

My result.

[image]

Because the two internal in client and the internal in your service is not the same, so your SetInternalNumber method will only set number to separate internal object and doesn't effect each other.

The client internal only has initial value of service internal and then has nothing to do with it and with each other. This is why your two client internal has the same initial number.

Comment: On one hand this makes sense, but on another it doesn’t.


What doesn’t make sense is how WCF creates a working Internal object on the client.  It shouldn’t know anything about the Internal class other than its method signatures.  How does the client side know anything about how Internal is implemented?  


Despite my issues, I believe my intent is clear: I want call methods on a server object.  How do I make this happen?  Do I need to redesign my service interface and/or classes?

Comment: Although you return an interface of IInternal , client will still rebuild an object of type Internal, you could find this through your attribute  [ServiceKnownType(typeof(Internal))]. As soon as you return your Internal , they have nothing to do with server side and will have their own number. You could try the code to Console.WriteLine(myInternal is Internal ? "yes" : "no"); to see the result. If you want to keep state , please don't return the interface, let server side change the state and return the state

Comment: I am starting to get a feel for what WCF is doing, but I still do not understand how it can put together a working object (Internal) on the client side.  How does it know the implementation of Internal?  It seems that it shouldn't.  If this were someone else's server, all I (and WCF) would have to work with is an interface.

Comment: When you call a method of client proxy, it will send message to server side, and server side will deserialize the message to build  parameter object  you need to pass to the method(off course it does a lot of other things.) When server side needs to return the result object , it will also send back the message , and client side will deserialize the message  to build the returned object.

Comment: The proxy part is what I was missing.  I think I was missing it partly due to self-hosting and my client creating its own channel.  I switched to using configuration, Add Service Reference, etc. and can now see a bit more of what is going on.  Thanks for your help.